# u_int64_t array

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, 64-bit

I'm trying to do this:

```
int main(void){
    u_int64_t NNUM = 2<<19;
    u_int64_t list[NNUM], i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){ 
        list[i] = 999;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting segfault at my Ubuntu 10.10 64 bits (gcc 4.6.1)?

Comment: Stackoverflow on StackOverflow... :)

Comment: The correct name is `uint64_t`, not `u_int64_t`. The latter is a legacy name that does not exist on standard C and is preserved in POSIX `sys/types.h` only for compatibility with legacy software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to create a very large array on the stack. This leads to a stack overflow.

Try allocating the array on the heap instead. For example:

```
// Allocate memory
u_int64_t *list = malloc(NNUM * sizeof(u_int64_t));

// work with `list`
// ...

// Free memory again
free(list);
```

Comment: What do you mean with heap? Sorry for the ignorance :)

Comment: You can accomplish this by making it a global (declared outside of `main()`) or making it `static` (which keeps it local to main).

Comment: Or by allocating the array using malloc.

Comment: No way to do something like this inside main? u_int64_t NNUM = 2<<19; static u_int64_t list[NNUM];

Comment: @FredericoSchardong That’s the second suggestion tomlogic made.

Comment: @LawrenceVelázquez I'm asking because gcc returns: error: storage size of ‘list’ isn’t constant

Answer (score 2):

You declare `NNUM = 2*2^19 ==  2<<19 ==  1048576`.

and try to allocate on the stack 64 bits * 1048576 = num of bits* num of cells.
It is `8.5 MegaBytes`, it is just too much for allocation on the stack, you can try to allocate it on the heap and check if it really works using the return value of `malloc`.

[heap VS. stack](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_difference_between_heap_memory_and_stack_memory)

Answer (score 0):

Your program requires a minimum stack size of 1048576,
if you check with 'ulimit -s', it is most likely less than that.
you can try 'ulimit -s 16384' and then re-execute again.